# "Multiple definition", "first defined here" errors

Tags: c, eclipse, include, definition, multiple-definition-error

I have 3 projects: *Server*, *Client* and *Commons*. Making header & source pairs in *Commons* doesn't cause any problems and I can access the functions freely from both *Server* and *Client*.

However, for some reason making additional source/header files within *Server* or *Client* project always causes `multiple definition of (...)` and `first defined here` errors.

Example:

**commands.h** (in root dir of the *Client* project)

```
#ifndef COMMANDS_H_
#define COMMANDS_H_

#include "commands.c"

void f123();

#endif /* COMMANDS_H_ */
```

**commands.c** (in root dir of the *Client* project)

```
void f123(){

}
```

**main.c** (in root dir of the *Client* project)

```
#include "commands.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv){

}
```

Errors:

```
make: *** [Client] Error 1      Client
first defined here              Client
multiple definition of `f123'   commands.c
```

Cleaning, rebuilding index, rebuilding projects doesn't help. Neither does restarting the computer.

Comment: Don't. Include. `*.c`. Files!

Comment: More to the point, don't `#include` C files.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem here is that you are including `commands.c` in `commands.h` before the function prototype. Therefore, the C pre-processor inserts the content of `commands.c` into `commands.h` before the function prototype. `commands.c` contains the function definition.  As a result,  the function definition ends up before than the function declaration causing the error.

The content of `commands.h` after the pre-processor phase looks like this:

```
#ifndef COMMANDS_H_
#define COMMANDS_H_

// function definition
void f123(){

}

// function declaration
void f123();

#endif /* COMMANDS_H_ */
```

This is an error because you can't declare a function after its definition in C. If you swapped `#include "commands.c"` and the function declaration the error shouldn't happen because, now, the function prototype comes before the function declaration.

However, including a `.c` file is a **bad practice** and should be avoided. A better solution for this problem would be to include `commands.h` in `commands.c` and link the compiled version of command to the main file. For example:

**commands.h**

```
#ifndef COMMANDS_H_
#define COMMANDS_H_

void f123(); // function declaration

#endif
```

**commands.c**

```
#include "commands.h"

void f123(){} // function definition
```

Comment: The key is to understand that you never include .c file. try including corresponding .h file instead

Comment: Even when not including `.c` files, this error can still occur if you _define_ a function in a header file. So unless you have a compelling reason for your code to be [header-only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header-only), you should always _declare_ your functions in the `.h` file, _define_ it in a corresponding `.c`, and only include the `.h` file.

Answer (score 30):

I had a similar issue when not using `inline` for my global function that was included in two places.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @AlexK. As I understand it...

Think of inline as static in this case. When the file is included from multiple sources it is only compiled once and references back to that original object are made on the proceeding uses.

Comment: This solution worked for me because I wanted to function definition to be present in header file only.

Comment: Oddly enough, this error only occured for me after moving from gcc 9 to gcc 10. Using `inline` saved me, thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much. I just want to say you have saved me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 7):

You should not include commands.c in your header file. In general, you should not include .c files. Rather, commands.c should include commands.h. As defined here, the C preprocessor is inserting the contents of commands.c into commands.h where the include is. You end up with two definitions of f123 in commands.h.

**commands.h**

```
#ifndef COMMANDS_H_
#define COMMANDS_H_

void f123();

#endif
```

**commands.c**

```
#include "commands.h"

void f123()
{
    /* code */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you included the `.c` file in makefile multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this A because I got caught with a bizarre version of this which really had me scratching my head for about a hour until I spotted the root cause.  My load was failing because of multiple repeats of this format

```
<path>/linit.o:(.rodata1.libs+0x50): multiple definition of `lua_lib_BASE'
<path>/linit.o:(.rodata1.libs+0x50): first defined here
```

I turned out to be a bug in my Makefile magic where I had a list of C files and using vpath etc., so the compiles would pick them up from the correct directory in hierarchy.  However one C file was repeated in the list, at the end of one line and the start of the next so the gcc load generated by the make had the `.o` file twice on the command line.  Durrrrh.  The multiple definitions were from multiple occurances of the same file.  The linker ignored duplicates apart from static initialisers!

Answer (score 3):

This error can also occur if the definitions are "header file only".
Example :

```
foo.h :
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
int myFunc(int a) {
 return a+2;
}

#endif

// There is no foo.c

// Main source files
file1.c :
#include "Foo.h"
<some code>

file2.c :
#include "Foo.h"
<some code>
```

Now both file1.c and file2.c contains definition of myFunc(). This will cause linker error when they are getting linked to same library.

Comment: How does one solve this case?

Comment: Move the definition to cpp file and keep only declaration in the header.